# Fetch very last recent single comments on each post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

Fetch very last recent single comments on each post

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM ( `comments` )
LEFT JOIN  `posts` 
       ON  `posts`.`id` =  `comments`.`case_id` 
    WHERE  `comments`.`user_id` =  '8'
 GROUP BY  `comments`.`case_id` 
 ORDER BY  `comments`.`created_date` DESC
```

Comment: Please try to rephrase this question. See [ask] for more details on how to get your chances up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not getting the list of post IDs belonging to that user:

```
SELECT posts.id
FROM posts
INNER JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.case_id
WHERE comments.user_id = 8
```

Then `foreach($IDs as $id)`:

```
SELECT * FROM comments
WHERE case_id = ${id}
ORDER BY created_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

---

*Original answer:*

You are just missing the `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT * from comments
LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.id = comments.case_id
WHERE comments.user_id = 8
GROUP BY comments.case_id
ORDER BY comments.created_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: he want last recent single comments on each post

Comment: Since the question is also tagged in PHP, I assume one can obtain the list of posts and loop through a query containing the LIMIT clause.

Comment: it listing only one post. I want every posts last comment given by user.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and let me know if it responds to your question:

```
SELECT * FROM comments 
RIGHT JOIN posts ON posts.id = comments.case_id 
WHERE comments.user_id = '8' AND comments.created_date = (SELECT MAX(created_date) FROM comments WHERE case_id = posts.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    posts
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.case_id = posts.post_id
WHERE
    comments.comments_id IN (
        SELECT
            MAX(comments_id)
        FROM
            comments
        GROUP BY
            case_id
    )
AND comments.user_id = '8'
```

Hope it helps